# No matching signature for operator = for argument types

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to connect two tables with a simple left outer join.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `database-dev.test_te.crawl_index_2022` as A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `database-dev.test_te.crawl_detail_2022` AS B ON A.spec_id = B.spec_id 
LIMIT 1000;
```

I want to shorten the part `database-dev.test_te.crawl_index_2022` using `AS`.

However, I get the following error message:

`No matching signature for operator = for argument types: INT64, STRING. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [4:82]`

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably

- `A.spec_id` is INT and  `B.spec_id` is a STRING.

So you need to use a `CAST(B.spec_id as INT64)`